# AngularJS strange query behavior with UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS. I'm using `$state.go()` in my search() on my ng-submit button. `searchTerms` is my ng-model on the input.

I have 2 controllers, homeCtrl and searchCtrl. homeCtrl is for homepage which is just a search box and provides autocomplete functionality. searchCtrl is for results page and has same search box and provides for results area.

When I have `$state.go()` like this:

```
$state.go('search', {q: searchTerms});
```

It solved a problem I was having, which was

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=searchTerms
```

INSTEAD of

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=userTypedInput
```

So now the url functions correctly, but the search results do not display...?

---

When I have

```
$state.go('search', {q: 'searchTerms'});
```

The search results display BUT the url does not function as desired.

So basically what I'm asking is how can I get my url to function as desired which is

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=userTypedInput
```

AND still have the search results display?

**UPDATE**
These are my states for ui router

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'})
  .state('search', {
    url: '/search?q',
    views: {
      '' : { templateUrl: 'search/search.html', controller: 'searchCtrl' }
      //add more views here when necessary
    }
  });
```

**searchCtrl**

I have this at the top

```
    'use strict';

angular.module("searchApp.search", ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', '$stateParams', '$state', 'searchService', function($scope, $sce, $stateParams, $state, searchService) {

  $scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.searchTerms || null;
```

and this is search(), which contains the `$state.go()`

```
    $scope.search = function() {
    resetResults();

    var searchTerms = $scope.searchTerms;

    if (searchTerms) {
      $scope.results.searchTerms = searchTerms;
    } else {
      return;
    }

    getResults();//calls searchService which does the searching

    $state.go('search', {q: searchTerms});
  };



var getResults = function() {
$scope.isSearching = true;

searchService.search($scope.results.searchTerms,$scope.currentPage,...
```

I'm trying to get the url to be

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=userTypedInput
```

and have the results display as well.

Comment: Disable `html5mode` and check, it will work otherwise let me know

Comment: @swapnesh I made html5mode false and no change, results still do not display

Comment: You haven't provided the necessary information to figure out the problem here.  ui-router is responsible for constructing the url and loading the page.  There's no way to know why the results aren't displaying from the code that you've posted

Comment: @user3125823 any error in console ?

Comment: @swapnesh no errors in console

Comment: @Austin ui-router must be affecting it somehow, its when I change $state.go that this happens

Comment: What is your concrete problem now? A correct url but no search results? This seems to be a problem with the initialization of the searchCtrl. Please provide the code you used in your searchCtrl, how you access the params there...

Comment: @ajaegle please see searchCtrl, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your state config you use the parameter name of `q` to pass the search query. This is the name, you also need to use when accessing the parameter from `$stateParams` in your `searchCtrl`. In the code shown above, your query will always be null, because you access the parameter named `searchQuery` which doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll make the corrections and report back here.

Comment: it seems the parameter that I use in my state config to pass the search query should also be the same as my ng-model on the input? Am I understanding this correctly now? I used q because its the name of the input.

Comment: been doing more reading and it seems if I just change my ng-model to "q" as well and replace searchTerms with q in the searchCtrl - everything should work as desired...